# Как SpinBox реализовать добавление или удаление полей текстового ввода

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt, pysimplegui, qspinbox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в *Python* (*Tkinter* или *PySimpleGUI*) с помощью `SpinBox` реализовать возможность добавления или удаления полей для ввода текста в главном окне программы путем увеличении или уменьшении значения `SpinBox`.

С помощью какого фреймворка это лучше реализовывать?

Comment: "С помощью какого фреймворка это лучше реализовывать?" - с помощью любого, в котором есть SpinBox или его аналог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более-менее минимальный пример на tkinter. Создаваемые текстовые поля добавляем в список. Отслеживаем изменение значения в `SpinBox`, если новое значение больше, чем полей уже существует - добавляем поля ввода, если меньше - удаляем.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

entries = []


def on_change():
    value = int(spinbox.get())
    if value > len(entries):
        entries.append(tk.Entry())
        entries[-1].pack()
    elif value < len(entries):
        entries.pop().destroy()


spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, command=on_change, state="readonly")
spinbox.set(0)
spinbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, а куда вставить такую же функцию для второго spinbox-a, чтобы получилось к каждой строке добавлять подстроки. По аналогии со строками и столбцами таблицы.

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Рядом и вставляйте. Где вам удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью любого фреймворка это можно реализовывать.

Использую *PyQt*, это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.setTitle(name.upper())        
        self.name = name

        self.lbl = QLabel(f'Label {self.name}')
        self.lbl.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)

        self.btn = QPushButton(f'Button {self.name}')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.printsignal)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(f'LineEdit {self.name}')

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)

    def printsignal(self):
        print(
            f"clicked: \n\tTitle    --> {self.title()}"
            f" \n\tLabel    --> {self.lbl.text()}"
            f" \n\tLineEdit --> {self.lineEdit.text()}"
        )


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        value = 12
        self._list = [f'item{i}' for i in range(1, value+1)]

        self.controls = QWidget()
        self.controlsLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.controls)

        self.widgets = []
        for name in self._list:
            item = Widget(name)
            self.controlsLayout.addWidget(item)
            self.widgets.append(item)

        spacer = QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.controlsLayout.addItem(spacer)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.controls)
 
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(1, 12)
        self.spinBox.setProperty("value", 12)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.update_display)        

        containerLayout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        containerLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)

    def update_display(self, value):
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            if i+1 <= value:
                widget.show()
            else:
                widget.hide()

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.scroll.widget().size() * 0.7
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*PyQt* — набор расширений графического фреймворка *Qt* для языка программирования *Python*, выполненный в виде расширения *Python*.

*PyQt* работает на всех платформах, поддерживаемых `Qt`: Linux и другие UNIX-подобные ОС, Mac OS X и Windows.